# Computer guessing number between user-inputted range

Tags: java, numbers

I'm trying to create a game using Java where the user is inputting two numbers to set a range, and the computer has to guess what the user's number is within that range.

Edit: Sorry for the terrible formatting! Here is my code. I've actually gotten it to work pretty well, my only issue is that if I were to input two values, say 1200 and 1400 when prompted, and my number in my head is say 1337. Telling the program that 1300 is too low and then 1350 is too high actually results in the computer printing 1275 as its 3rd guess. I was wondering how I could make it print the average of 1300 and 1350 (1325) as its 3rd guess, instead of printing 1275.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  int lowerLimit = 0;
  int upperLimit = 0;
  int middleNumber = 0;
  char userInput = 'a';
  int almostLower = 0;
  int almostUpper = 0;

  System.out.println("Your number is in this range... (enter 2 numbers)");
  lowerLimit = scnr.nextInt();
  upperLimit = scnr.nextInt();
  middleNumber = (lowerLimit + upperLimit) / 2;

  almostLower = lowerLimit + 1;
  almostUpper = upperLimit - 1;

  System.out.print("Type 'h' for 'too high', 'l' for 'too low',");
  System.out.println(" and 'c' if I got it right."); //line too long

  do {
    System.out.println("Is it " + middleNumber + "?");
    userInput = scnr.next().charAt(0); 

    if (userInput == 'c') {
      System.out.println("I always win");
      break;
    }

    else if (userInput == 'h') { 

      if (middleNumber == almostLower) {
          System.out.println("Is it " + lowerLimit + "?"); 
          userInput = scnr.next().charAt(0);

          if (userInput == 'c') {
            System.out.println("I always win");
            break;
          }
      }
      else {
        middleNumber = calcMidNum(lowerLimit, middleNumber);
      }
    }

    else if (userInput == 'l') {

      if (middleNumber == almostUpper) {
        System.out.println("Is it " + upperLimit + "?"); 
        userInput = scnr.next().charAt(0);

        if (userInput == 'c') {
          System.out.println("I always win");
          break;
        }            
      }
      else {
        middleNumber = calcMidNum(middleNumber, upperLimit);
      }
  }
  } while (userInput != 'c');  
 }
 public static int calcMidNum(int a, int b) {
   int calcMid = (a + b) / 2;
   return calcMid;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please post pertinent code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), here with your question, not in a link. Links can go dead, and links may hold large programs, programs too large to ask a volunteer to review. Your compliance with this request will be greatly appreciated and will likely help you in getting better and faster help.

Comment: Even worse, your link is to an **image**, and there's no way we can copy, paste and try to run an image -- it just won't work. So again, post your code as formatted **text** here with your question.

Comment: For more on how to improve this question and your future questions, please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works.

Comment: Also, instead of *I'm not sure how I can get it to work correctly*, you should be very specific about the issue/error. Maybe write the expected and observed behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not adjust the lower and upper limits.

Try this:

```
...
else if (userInput == 'h') { 
    upperLimit = middleNumber;
...
```

and

```
...
else if (userInput == 'l') {
    lowerLimit = middleNumber;
...
```